# Rails Has_Many :Through Not Working In RSpec / Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

While it works in development and in production, once I attempt to leverage the has_many :through relationship in either RSpec or in Cucumber, it return nil. As such:

The Order model (simplified):

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shipping_address, through :checkout
end
```

The Checkout model (simplified):

```
class Checkout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :shipping_address, :class_name => 'ShippingAddress', :as => :addressable
end
```

The Spec:

```
describe "shipping_address" do
  it "should return a ShippingAddress" do

    @order.checkout.shipping_address.is_a? ShippingAddress  # return true
    @order.shipping_address.is_a?          ShippingAddress  # returns false (is NilClass)

  end
end
```

Comment: Your Order model shows a `shipping_address` but your spec is talking about a `billing_address`. Can you post the appropriate model code for the `billing_address`?

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out. There is actually both a shipping and billing address. They are the same except for the class. I changed billing_address to shipping_address to avoid confusion.

Comment: The spec fragment you're sharing doesn't define `@order`. Would you please share all the relevant portions of your spec as well as the output you're receiving? It's not possible to evaluate what's going on with various expressions involving `@order` without knowing how the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use belongs_to instead of has_one in your Checkout model association definition.
As stated in the has_one method docs:

> Specifies a one-to-one association with another class. This method should only be used if the other class contains the foreign key. If the current class contains the foreign key, then you should use +belongs_to+ instead.

and here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html